# Program compatibility troubleshoot broke Roblox

Tags: windows, windows-11

I read online that the program compatibility troubleshooter helps with performance.

I ran it on Roblox and used windows 8 (yes very stupid of me) and now I can't go back to windows 11 for Roblox.

I reinstalled it and tried the Microsoft store one.

Can I change it back or am I stuck?

Comment: `now I can't go back to windows 11 for Roblox` .. what does this mean?  Does it crash?  What happens?

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas The torso doesn't render, some body parts missing + textures (I already had this problem but it got worse)

Comment: Have you tried simply right-clicking the .exe -> properties.. and looking at the compatability tab?

Comment: One can also delete the existing shortcut and recreate it

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Oh...... So it wasn't in windows 8. The problem is just with Roblox itself.

Comment: I am not sure @Ramhound but the settings created by the troubleshooter used to be stored in `Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers` and not the shortcut.  The property sheet for apps and shortcuts I believe get data from there.  It isn't defined in the Shell Link (.LNK) Binary File Format.